# Auto generate bill no in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am generating Bill No in my PHP MySQL code with following code and it's working fine (`billno` is field and iap3 is table name in mysql. It's an auto-increment bill no on the basis of previously added value in database table).

But I want that it should generate Bill No in following order and as follows

```
B-0000-0001
```

`B` represent company, then next 2 zero show  month of current date (for example as today month is 09), then next 2 zero show year of current date (for example 23) and in the end 0001 increment per patient.

When month and year change, then this last 0001 should reset to 0001 again. How can I do this?

Help from this forum required to solve my query

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT bilno FROM iap3 ORDER BY bilno DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$lastid = $row['bilno'];
if(empty($lastid))
{
    $number = "B-00001";
}
else
{
    $idd = str_replace("B-", "", $lastid);
    $id = str_pad($idd + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $number = 'B-'.$id;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your current code isn't doing anything with dates. Is `B-` in the db already? Where does "company" come from? Can you provide expected result, e.g. what `B-0000-0001` should become. Is the patient an id in db or unique auto-incrementing value for every visitor?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? BTW as well as the calculations of the numbers, you have the additional issue that this will be prone to race conditions and runs a risk of creating duplicate bill numbers. I would strongly suggest just letting the database generate a unique ID using autoincrement, then it is guaranteed to be unique. If you want to work out how many bills were raised in a given month, leave that to your application's reporting tools rather than attempting to count it via the ID. I don't see what benefits you will gain by creating this extra complexity with the IDs

Comment: i will use it for hospital management system, and its my customer requirements, duplication cant be occurred as month and year will change when last four digit will reset on the basis of month and year change

Comment: Can you please paste iap3 database table structure?

Comment: It might be easier if you used an autoincrement id, then calculate the `bilno` (at least the incrementing part) by taking that autogenerated id and subtracting the id of the first record with the same year/month.  You could even move this logic into the database with a trigger, and so `bilno` would automatically get added for every new record.

Comment: `duplication cant be occurred `...it can, if the php code is executed by two different users at once. Make sure you understand what a race condition is.

Comment: @Rohit  id, bilno, name,  age  (id is autoincrement field as well as primary key)

Comment: @ADyson, I will set billno as unique key in database, so duplication record will npt be saved. an u guide if I only reset last 4 digit (0001) only when year changed, how can i implement it ?

Comment: @user3783243 yes current code only auto increment field after B-. but i want it should work with month and year. auto increment with same month and year. and reset when month and year chnaged

Comment: @Rob Eyre is there any example available

Comment: @Umar you can do one thing add one more column in the the table called date, then whenever you select first check the higher bill number of the current date and then increment bill number.

later you can convert the date in any format and add zero padding as you need to show the bill number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in the database with a standard auto-incrementing id column, a timestamp and a trigger.

For demonstration, here is a table `mytable`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int not null primary key auto_increment,
  created timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  bilno char(11),
  something varchar(100),
  otherthing varchar(100)
);
```

We now set up a trigger that fires whenever we insert a row:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_ins BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE minId INT default 0;

    SET @myId := (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE());

    SET @minId := (SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM mytable
        WHERE YEAR(created) = YEAR(NEW.created)
        AND MONTH(created) = MONTH(NEW.created));

    IF @minId IS NULL THEN
        SET @bilId = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @bilId = 1 + @myId - @minId;
    END IF;

    SET NEW.bilno = CONCAT('B',
        '-', DATE_FORMAT(NEW.created, "%m%y"),
        '-', LPAD(@bilId, 4, '0')
    );

END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Since the value of the auto-incrementing column isn't available at the time that the BEFORE INSERT trigger fires, we get this instead from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.  (Important caveat: this solution will therefore only work for rows inserted one at a time)

We then compare the id of the row we're inserting with the lowest id that's already been inserted for this month.  If there is no prior id, then we are the first so assign the bil number '1'.  If there is a prior id, then subtract the two ids to get the bil number.

Finally, format the result nicely, including the month and date.

To test, create some historic data:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('c');
UPDATE mytable SET
    bilno = REPLACE(bilno, DATE_FORMAT(created, "%m%y"), '0823'),
    created = '2023-08-04 18:43:11';
```

and create some new data:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('d');
INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('e');
```

Check the result:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;

+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| id | created             | bilno       | something | otherthing |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 2023-08-04 18:43:11 | B-0823-0001 | a         | NULL       |
|  2 | 2023-08-04 18:43:11 | B-0823-0002 | b         | NULL       |
|  3 | 2023-08-04 18:43:11 | B-0823-0003 | c         | NULL       |
|  4 | 2023-09-05 19:17:13 | B-0923-0001 | d         | NULL       |
|  5 | 2023-09-05 19:17:13 | B-0923-0002 | e         | NULL       |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
```